# Android NDK usage

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I'm trying to push a byte array from android to native where I convert it to cv::Mat and call a method that gives back cv::Point2d coordinates. I want to put these coordintes into a vector or list or something that I can get back on android. I searched a lot but didn't find anything I could use. I'd like to ask for a solution how to put them into a data structure that I can use on android.

Also if I add

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
```

into my .mk file the STL data structures are same as android ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to return a STL type to Android that Java can directly handle ? If that's the case, that's not possible.

You can use Java objects and arrays directly from your native code. You need to make [JNI calls](https://thenewcircle.com/static/bookshelf/java_fundamentals_tutorial/_java_native_interface_jni.html) to create and populate them.

APP_STL := stlport_static will only make your native code use the stlport library to have STL support in your project (the default lib doesn't support anything).

Comment: I think I've already solved the problem, but thanks anyway. That was the case tho.